# Printing all ASCII characters from 0 to 255

Tags: c++, ascii, cout

If `unsigned char` ranges from 0 to 255,shouldn't is be able to print all the ASCII characters (even with values greater than 127)?

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main(){

    for(int i=0 ; i <= 255 ; i++)
        cout << "ASCII NUMBER" << i << ':' << (unsigned char)i << endl;


    return 0;

}
```

The code above works as expected for the characters from 0 to 127, but not above from that.
How may one print these characters?

Comment: What _characters_ did you expect?

Comment: ASCII only knows 128 characters.

Comment: All ASCII characters do not have a specific character to represent them. Some of them are keys like `Escape`, `Backspace` etc. Usually, characters with representable symbols begin with `32` and end at `127`. Look at the ASCII table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) as reference.

Comment: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is only defined in 0-127 range. What do you except?

Comment: there are ascii characters that are not printable

Comment: Then what would the use of ``unsigned char`` be? In the following image: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftheasciicode.com.ar%2F&psig=AOvVaw2eoxXC5IY6ewtGRAp7nwjK&ust=1592758219698000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMjZvfLskOoCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD                                                                                                                There are these "extended ASCII" characters.Can't they be used?

Comment: It seems you should configure your terminal or text viewer application to treat the input as proper charcter code and use proper font to display the characters.

Comment: The [`std::isgraph`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isgraph) can help you determine if the character has a graphic representation.  (Space is not such a character, but if you'd want to consider it as such, then `std::isprint` instead.)

Comment: `Then what would the use of unsigned char be?` `unsigned char` represents a _byte_, not a _character_. `"extended ASCII" characters.Can't they be used?` This depends on where you _print_ / _view_ the data. The device that displays the bytes has to support "extended ASCII" (or the [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) you want to use).

Comment: `unsigned char` is a misleading name. It's a one-byte number. It's not a character

Comment: @zach `unsigned char` is not necessarily the type for Extended ASCII set. It's just an unsigned wrapper for `signed char` (or just `char`). When you try to print it, it will just wrap around and work like a normal `-127` to `128` `signed char`. [You may look at this article to see what happens when you try to print negative values of char in the console.](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/negative-ascii-codes/)

Comment: @ThomasSablik That solves it. So it's a way to store a number ranging strictly from 0 to 255. That helped for sure,but if there is such thing as "extended ASCII" shouldn't they be printable?

Comment: Extended ASCII is a terrible, terrible name. Everyone had their own idea of which characters should go there, so there are many different sets of characters that they could be (known as code pages). This is maximum non-portable stuff and the odds you have something display right somewhere and wrong somewhere else are fairly high because to display these, you have to pick a code page and there's no way to tell what the intended one is. Thank god Unicode came along and created a standard we can more or less agree upon, though even that isn't that simple.

Comment: Speaking of code pages, the diagram you meant to link to (but got google's intermediate URL instead) is actually [Code Page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). There are many others and you can go see the differences. You can even change the console's code page and watch the same program produce completely different output. If this topic piques your interest, there's a [great talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOHnXt3Ycfo) on it from a few years back.

Answer (score 0):

A simple program like this will print the ASCII character represented by the each number from 0-255.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
        std::cout << (unsigned char)i << " " << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

I have logged both the ASCII character and its value as an integer. As you will see in the output if you run it, after the value 127, you will get strange characters. On my Linux machine, the terminal printed this character for the values of 128-255 `�`.

A simple resource such as http://www.asciitable.com/ will show you all ASCII characters. It shows the "normal" ASCII characters (0-127) and a separate table displaying "extended" ASCII characters (128-255). You will not be able to print the extended ASCII characters.
**To answer your question, no, you cannot print the ASCII characters with values of greater than 127.**
However, there is a solution that is a bit of a hack to print one of these characters. Look at the resource http://www.asciitable.com/ again. As an example, I used the ASCII character with a value of 219, `█`. Simply copy-and-pasting this character will print the character successfully (at least, on my machine).
For example, this code will work:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        std::cout << "█";
    }
}
```

I hope this answers any questions you may have